# Why Visual Studio thinks .csproj.user is a dependency of the solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build, devenv

I have built my solution completely in the IDE. Closed the solution, then reopened it. Then I build it again and see the following in the diag build log:

```
Project 'MyApp' is not up to date. Input file 'C:\abc\UI\MyApp.csproj.user' is modified after output file 'C:\abc\UI\bin\Dayforce.Web.Main.pdb'.
```

I beg your pardon? Why? How? What for?

My question is how do I prevent it. Thanks.

P.S.

I am using VS 2012 to build C#, Silverlight, Web apps. All types are found in that one solution. This question is related to two of my other questions in the same area - [Why msbuild is so slow when nothing has changed since the last build of the solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704068/why-msbuild-is-so-slow-when-nothing-has-changed-since-the-last-build-of-the-solu) and [Building the same solution using msbuild and devenv interchangeably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702989/building-the-same-solution-using-msbuild-and-devenv-interchangeably)

**EDIT**

Here is the content of the .csproj.user file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <StartPageUrl>
          </StartPageUrl>
          <StartAction>CurrentPage</StartAction>
          <AspNetDebugging>True</AspNetDebugging>
          <SilverlightDebugging>False</SilverlightDebugging>
          <NativeDebugging>False</NativeDebugging>
          <SQLDebugging>False</SQLDebugging>
          <ExternalProgram>
          </ExternalProgram>
          <StartExternalURL>
          </StartExternalURL>
          <StartCmdLineArguments>
          </StartCmdLineArguments>
          <StartWorkingDirectory>
          </StartWorkingDirectory>
          <EnableENC>False</EnableENC>
          <AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>True</AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>
          <ProjectOutputReferences>
            <Ref Project="{7E7D4772-17CC-4E48-881A-2B6C74AA9115}" Folder="ClientBin">FJ.Core.zip|Main.xap|NLogSL5.zip|SharpZipLib.Silverlight4.zip|SLVisifire.Charts.zip|System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.zip|System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit.zip|System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input.zip|System.Windows.Controls.Data.zip|System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.zip|System.Windows.Controls.Input.zip|System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit.zip|System.Windows.Controls.Navigation.zip|System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals.zip|System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.zip|System.Windows.Controls.zip|System.Windows.Data.zip|System.Windows.Interactivity.zip|System.Xml.Linq.zip|System.Xml.Serialization.zip</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{10A594D6-565A-489B-BFEB-562E4AF8F524}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.Analytics.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{118A0F63-3A73-46F8-8EFB-7DA662783BE8}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.ApprovalRequest.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{A9F9B1E7-A63A-4B7C-801D-7A8F06172CBC}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.EssTimeClock.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{95230DD6-71DA-4088-A428-9ECB0E6F4C62}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.BudgetIt.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{85B88B3C-E577-4CE9-87AD-B0C9EF0BEFFE}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.HRAdmin.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{59DE9CE6-F753-43CA-A05B-703DD404A64F}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.OrgAdmin.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{FA20A509-F562-408B-8BC9-2A8C7647C89D}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.PayAdmin.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{B93D4233-8005-4E40-806A-B43A82BAEC9B}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.PlanAdmin.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{0841A4EC-8FBE-4AD7-A8E9-D0418D922353}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.PlanIt.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{123CD732-D193-44F6-9FFE-77EC351F7889}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.ScheduleAdmin.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{430B2A78-7177-43EF-8582-8D73349A2FAE}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.SiteAdmin.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{23002B33-7F3E-4531-9BB6-35A31623FE62}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.SystemAdmin.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{0E642295-C251-4008-968F-C001CD28E82A}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.TaskManagement.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{A2E6437F-C084-44FC-A7F7-A1173DAFF717}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.TrainingAdmin.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{AB2F02DD-F23F-4AB2-ACB3-B8D196E0407B}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyAttendance.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{FE8CE4BE-8857-4339-91F7-56EB371ECC07}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyAvailability.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{FC1515FB-FDC1-4612-83EA-289AE013BB81}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyEmployees.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{71C906DD-F065-4880-B28D-CFCC121EFCF9}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyHRIncidents.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{942752C6-19FF-475C-BBDC-BECDF3713718}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyOps.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{D090382A-41D1-4336-9D98-24B9FD5C9F76}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyPayroll.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{31A989BA-7E4C-4D3A-BD49-8EAFA5F795E3}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyProjects.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{FEBBA4C6-F268-464C-BFF0-7539FA08D1C5}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MySchedules.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{6BC5170E-EC18-4BE7-917C-71F0E1F788B0}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyTimeCard.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{F141FDDC-66A6-4AFE-9341-740CF16796E1}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyTimesheet.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{5EC82D69-9A8F-4B7E-BF3C-DF87E825931C}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.PlanningChecklist.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{620AAFF3-AAE1-4614-8160-DFF16195DB4C}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.ScheduleBidding.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{58D91BB4-7EBF-4B6C-9507-4D784731F3A3}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.Scheduler.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{38C9D0B1-9ECD-4D16-B6C1-91FBD6D05A2C}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.TasksChecklist.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{436FAE0C-1887-43EF-BCAA-FF616D8032B3}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.TimeOffRequest.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{3107385A-CE43-44B7-879B-5DB15A5AD048}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.TimeSheet.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{DD26CC37-DE7A-426B-A950-987AF7D152AA}" Folder="ClientBin">MainEx.xap|System.Xml.Serialization.zip</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{08B99555-416A-4E08-8ACD-4F3CB9962D62}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.OvertimeEqualizer.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{D2C2D3C8-DEBE-41E7-B4B2-AC880F0C9582}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyEarnings.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{C398EB76-CC2D-4F63-B1D7-7F07E7641261}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.SystemAdministration.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{8E83F545-1F0C-4FA6-8EF5-E9C6E8121A02}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.PayrollAdmin.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{5B8E5027-FE5C-4F61-88D1-999B06882C3B}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyPayPage.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{764A5AF4-7C66-4107-88A8-4C64939457AD}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyPayCard.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{850375FE-38BA-4F84-8F89-E70972EFF41C}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.PayrollManagement.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{CD4BB2FA-A9BC-45E3-BDA4-7406E8A55BBB}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.VacationBidding.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{EA82FB73-57D3-406F-B5F4-129229E861D5}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.BenefitsAdmin.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{CED69380-A039-456D-B1DD-17680F87AF4D}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.BenefitsManagement.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{63183916-E9A6-4223-A427-47DA67FD2FF7}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyBenefits.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{E74D3116-CA96-48DF-B5F2-3F5C6F39D668}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyYearEnd.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{CCFBEAA2-C666-4B60-840B-AC362EEEE3E5}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.PunchAuditing.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{E0C76603-65DF-4CAD-91A5-E65B2ADB78C6}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.SchedulePlanning.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{E3D5DBCD-A500-4D84-8874-42D9F6D227A5}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.MyProjectChecklist.xap</Ref>
            <Ref Project="{6518D41F-F2D3-460C-B468-67C35825779D}" Folder="ClientBin">abc.TaskPlanningCalendar.xap</Ref>
          </ProjectOutputReferences>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

Note, that I did not change any configuration options. Just opening,closing,building the solution.

Comment: Post the content of a file so we don't have to guess what setting might have changed.